# Unity Starts so late after start up

Tags: 16.04, unity

I have installed ubuntu 16.04 on my laptop. When turning on and logging in, I get a screen with wallpaper and mouse cursor and without panel, dash or ability to open a window, etc. It takes about 5-15 minutes to start the unity desktop. I first thought it does not load at all like this problem: [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears).

the `systemd-analyze blam` output is:

```
    1min 39.191s vboxdrv.service
     18.274s mysql.service
     14.793s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
     10.758s dev-sda3.device
      9.964s ModemManager.service
      8.317s apache2.service
      5.701s NetworkManager.service
      5.284s systemd-cryptsetup@cryptswap1.service
      4.589s accounts-daemon.service
      3.997s apparmor.service
      3.376s systemd-udevd.service
      3.302s thermald.service
      3.248s grub-common.service
      2.859s gpu-manager.service
      2.710s apport.service
      2.629s polkitd.service
      2.232s colord.service
      2.124s ondemand.service
      1.867s irqbalance.service
      1.772s systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-736fbfa7\x2d20ca\x2d4666\x2d897c\x2d6f89f2eadd57.service
      1.678s lightdm.service
      1.424s bluetooth.service
      1.393s speech-dispatcher.service
      1.367s systemd-modules-load.service
      1.346s systemd-logind.service
      1.193s console-setup.service
      1.184s upower.service
      1.184s avahi-daemon.service
      1.165s systemd-user-sessions.service
      1.165s rsyslog.service
      1.140s keyboard-setup.service
      1.075s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
      1.014s udisks2.service
       989ms alsa-restore.service
       986ms systemd-journald.service
       910ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
       835ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
       835ms dev-hugepages.mount
       796ms home.mount
       650ms dev-mqueue.mount
       629ms systemd-rfkill.service
       552ms kmod-static-nodes.service
       496ms networking.service
       444ms wpa_supplicant.service
       423ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-3d4e4ad3\x2d6a00\x2d4e37\x2db86f\x2dd6374c5e059f.service
       359ms boot.mount
       322ms user@1000.service
       321ms pppd-dns.service
       306ms ufw.service
       299ms dns-clean.service
       266ms systemd-backlight@backlight:acpi_video1.service
       238ms systemd-sysctl.service
       192ms systemd-journal-flush.service
       176ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
       146ms systemd-remount-fs.service
       143ms systemd-random-seed.service
       132ms resolvconf.service
       130ms systemd-backlight@backlight:acpi_video0.service
       124ms dev-mapper-cryptswap1.swap
       103ms systemd-timesyncd.service
        59ms rtkit-daemon.service
        55ms systemd-update-utmp.service
        31ms systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service
        29ms setvtrgb.service
        13ms plymouth-start.service
        12ms plymouth-read-write.service
        12ms snapd.autoimport.service
         8ms ureadahead-stop.service
         5ms vboxweb-service.service
         5ms vboxballoonctrl-service.service
         4ms vboxautostart-service.service
         3ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
         2ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
         1ms plymouth-quit-wait.service
         1ms rc-local.service
       677us snapd.socket
```

Comment: paste the results of `systemd-analyze blame`

Answer (score 0):

have you tried all the above methods explained in your link.
you can also try:

```
apt-get --reinstall install unity
```

and if not succeed then,

```
apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

Comment: yes. None of them worked.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem was having lots of dotfiles. Since I had moved lots of (about 1 gig) applications to `.local/share/applications` , The unity has become too slow.